# Unable to run debug mode in VS 2017 on a project

Tags: c#

I am trying to run a debug mode but nothing happens. When i look at the output window there is a error msg saying :

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
The program '[9876] FarmBrowser.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[9876] FarmBrowser.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[9876] FarmBrowser.exe: Managed (v4.6, v4.5, v4.0)' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

I've tried almost everithing....

Comment: Open the folder the solution is held in.  Close Visual Studio and try deleting the .vs folder

Comment: Well it looks like your app is trying to use a file that doesn't exist. Without seeing your code though, we cannot possibly help. Which line throws this error? Have you tried to debug? Do you know how to debug?

Comment: Try adding a handler to the `UnhandledException` event of the `AppDomain` to capture the error.  Alternatively, under the Debug -> Exceptions menu, enable break on all exceptions

Comment: @KenTucker How would that possibly help at all?

Comment: You can't debug when you can't get the program started.  You might get a better diagnostic when you use Tools > Options > Debugging > General, "Use Managed Compatibility Mode", the old debugging engine is better at showing mishaps that occur at program start.

Comment: The issue is your project is attempting to use a 'legacy' debugger component that is no longer included in VS 2017

Comment: i tried all of your suggestions and it didnt work....